# jQuery Resize On Less than Width

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to make a jQuery function to change a div to basically float left when my site with Bootstrap 3 framework goes into mobile view (<750px on .container).

```
$(function() {

    var container_width_checker = $('.container').css(width);

    var container_width = function(){

        if (container_width_checker < 750px ) { 
            $('.accountcustom').css({ 'float': 'none', 'padding-left': '10px', });
            $('#shopping_cart a').css({ 'float': 'none', 'padding-left': '10px', });
        } else {
            $('.accountcustom').css({ 'float': 'right', }); 
            $('#shopping_cart a').css({ 'float': 'right', });
        }   
    };

    container_width();

    $(window).resize(function() {
         container_width();
    });

});
```

Am I approaching this correctly with the resize jQuery function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but `container_width_checker` needs to be calculated on each resize. As is, it's only being calculated once.

```
if ($('.container').width() < 750) {
```

It may be better, however, to look into media queries instead.

Comment: Yeah, I feel stupid because I should have used media queries.. but I do appreciate you explaining the issue. That helps me understand what I was doing wrong. :) Thanks Jason. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see CSS media queries and leave jQuery.

Here there are some additional info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Ah! Don't know what I was thinking.. thanks for pointing that out. Worked perfectly, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.width()` will allow you to work with a purely numerical value rather than the unit of measure.

```
$(function() {
    var container_width = function(){
        var container_width_checker = $('.container').width();
         if (container_width_checker < 750 ) { 
            $('.accountcustom').css({ 'float': 'none', 'padding-left': '10px', });
            $('#shopping_cart a').css({ 'float': 'none', 'padding-left': '10px', });
        } else {
            $('.accountcustom').css({ 'float': 'right', }); 
            $('#shopping_cart a').css({ 'float': 'right', });
        }   
    };
    container_width();
    $(window).resize(function() {
         container_width();
    });
});
```